# Should scriptural interpretation questions be off topic?

Tags: discussion

I mostly participate in the [Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/), but will occasionally check out a few questions on this site. For obvious reasons, these two sister sites are very closely-knit due to the adjacency of the topics, with many contributors participating on both sites.

[I](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50887/what-is-the-origin-of-throwing-dust-over-head-as-a-sign-of-mourning-in-the-bib/56640#56640) have [frequently](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/40324/how-did-cain-kill-abel) noticed [questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60151/was-barnabas-land-ownership-as-a-levite-against-mosaic-law) on [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27206/how-could-stephen-be-stoned-without-a-trial-and-conviction-in-front-of-the-roman) site [that](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44132/why-jeremiah-105-was-changed-from-palm-trees-to-scarecrows) would [be](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/522/what-is-significant-about-the-torn-curtain-what-about-jesus-death-impressed-th/45819#45819) a [perfect](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/why-are-thighs-important) fit [for](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/why-are-the-ammonites-excluded-instead-of-the-midianites-in-nehemiah-13/40114#40114) the [Hermeneutics](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/are-there-two-different-creation-accounts-in-the-bible/33749#33749) SE, and [some](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8451/when-was-egypt-uninhabited-for-40-years-migrated-from-christianity-se) of [them](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/14021/what-does-it-mean-for-the-kingdom-of-heaven-to-suffer-violence/25533) are [migrated](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27062/what-does-james-117-mean-by-perfect-gift/27063#27063), but [I](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59849/did-jesus-work-for-a-living) also [see](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59797/why-does-jesus-in-matthew-1815-17-seem-to-think-gentiles-and-tax-collectors-are) a [lot](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/36467/if-jesus-is-the-son-of-god-then-why-bother-listing-his-genealogy/46020#46020)
 of [questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59864/anah-contradictions-in-genesis) that [would](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59657/romans-65-and-wheres-wolfius) be [a](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59573/what-scriptures-was-paul-referring-to-in-1-corinthians-153-4) perfect [fit](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59570/how-many-new-testament-manuscripts-do-we-have-from-the-period-between-the-first) pass [by](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59485/was-psalms-456-mistranslated) without [migration](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/in-matthew-544-what-is-meant-by-enemies). The Hermeneutics SE is actually one of the 5 oldest sites that have not been [promoted from beta according to Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=newest&page=12) and has [been around](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/why-biblical-hermeneutics-isnt-closing/314#314) for a [very long](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/current-situation-for-hermeneutics-se-nov-2013/763#763) time and I notice that amongst the oldest sites, the most common metric lacking a green status is the "number of questions per day" metric.

I know that the Christianity SE began about two years earlier than Hermeneutics, and even after that it may not have been clear if the site would pass beta, so it is understandable that Christianity.SE might take general Biblical interpretation questions historically, but now that there is a dedicated SE for these types of questions, should Christianity.SE continue to accept these types of questions?

If not, should they be migrated? I know that often, questions are closed with a post notice stating,

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

Should questions of this type be closed with this status? It seems to me that by migrating questions of these types, it would allow the Hermeneutics SE to better flourish (and perhaps escape beta purgatory) and allow Christianity.SE to better focus on providing quality content of the type at which it excels. In short, should these types of questions continue to be considered on-topic?

Comment: Many of the newly asked questions are already migrated. So it's more what to do with the old ones (which can't be migrated either.)

Comment: Consider taking what you have written here and formulating a recommendation in an answer on the target question.  Existing answers haven't attracted much support, but perhaps a post that better captures the big picture of the interaction between BH and Christianity would do better.

Comment: @Nathaniel - I'll see about working up an answer tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this flowchart](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/867/a-helpful-flowchart-for-asking-questions-on-bh-se) when considering whether to migrate a question to Hermeneutics.  So far, I think I've migrated 2 questions since becoming a moderator a few months ago.

As a moderator, I only want to migrate questions in a form that I'd feel comfortable asking on the other site.

I'd migrate these questions:

[In Matthew 5:44, what is meant by "enemies"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/in-matthew-544-what-is-meant-by-enemies)

[Was Psalms 45:6 Mistranslated?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59485/was-psalms-456-mistranslated)

[What Scriptures was Paul referring to in 1 Corinthians 15:3-4](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59573/what-scriptures-was-paul-referring-to-in-1-corinthians-153-4)

[Was Barnabas' land ownership as a Levite against Mosaic Law?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60151/was-barnabas-land-ownership-as-a-levite-against-mosaic-law)

The rest (and maybe some of these) are either too old or specifically asking for Christian Doctrine (a few are Catholicism questions)

[This one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59618/in-matthew-544-what-is-meant-by-enemies) should be closed in Christianity.SE since it's more doctrinal than anything else.

---

Also mods want flags and/or close votes to initiate migration.

Comment: So of the 20 questions I linked, most of them were culled from the most recent questions. Which of those do you feel aren't a good fit for BH.SE and why?

Comment: I'll start flagging if people are amenable to it. For my reference: How old is too old to migrate? I'll flag the others requesting a historical lock.

Comment: @james 60 days https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days